# Stop php from rounding values

Tags: php

I have a form with text fields that I enter numbers in, and anytime I enter a "2.5" or a "3.5" or any number with a ".5", and I click submit, it rounds the number up. So 2.5 becomes 3, 3.5 becomes 4, and so on. How can I make this stop?

EDIT: I posted the wrong code, updated with correct code.

Here is the submit action:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'Update') {
foreach($_POST['game'] as $game) {

    $homeOdds = $game['homeScore'];
    $visitorOdds = $game['visitorScore'];

    $sql = "update " . $db_prefix . "schedule ";
    $sql .= " set homeOdds = " . $homeOdds . ", visitorOdds = " . $visitorOdds . "";
    $sql .= " where gameID = " . $game['gameID'];
    mysql_query($sql) or die('Error updating odds: ' . mysql_error());
}
//header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Why did you make that excerpt substitute `"\xBD"` for `".5"`? (Though I doubt that's where the rounding originates). Isn't it more likely the table scheme would be relevant?

Comment: Can you show your table schema? It's most likely your column definition (*type*) doing it.

Comment: I edited the post, I was using that but don't need it any longer. The `$game['homeScore'];` returns the value... usually has a number with .5 (like 2.5 or 3.5)

Comment: Table types for those 2 values are `int(3)` is that wrong?

Comment: An integer is a whole number... what did you think would happen if you stuff a decimal into it?

Comment: Integers are for whole numbers, hence the rounding. What you want is a fractioned number column. Something like `float`/`double`/`decimal` would do. You're best to read about [Mysql Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

Comment: `float` worked perfectly. Thank you! That was the last place I was looking... post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085837/stop-php-from-rounding-values#comment52067651_32085837), you can't use a whole number column (`int`) as it'll round it to a whole number.

What you want is a fractioned number column, either of the following would suffice:

- `float`
- `decimal`
- `double`
- ....etc

You should also read about [MySQL's Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html).